# Prevent shutdown, reboot etc. for the remote control via TeamViewer

Tags: reboot, remote-control, teamviewer, remote-shutdown

Is it possible to configurate the TeamViewer so the user can't performs the shutdown, reboot, lock user, log off etc. via remote control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really doubt it. I don't think the computer can tell the difference between input from a user sitting at the computer, and from someone connecting through Teamviewer. You'd probably need to disable it completely on the computer, and require a password to re-enable those controls.

Comment: Indeed, TeamViewer relays input and display in the simplest way, and if a program calls ExitWindowsEx(), Windows has absolutely no way of knowing whether it was initiated over TeamViewer or not.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought.

Answer (score 1):

my biggest issue was that the remote user would exit the Teamviewer program without my knowledge, thus I could not remote in when I needed to. TO solve problem, started teamviewer on remote, clicked on extras and then options. Clicked on advanced, and then "show advanced options" Scrolled down and put a check mark in "disable teamviewer shutdown" Clicked ok. Now they cant close teamviewer.

Another trick is to hide tray icons. this requires using the regedit command. see the following.

Follow the procedure given below to implement the registry edit to hide all the system tray icons in your sidebar.

1. Open Start Menu >> Run, type regedit and press Enter
2. Navigate to the following path 
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ 
   Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
3. Create a DWORD value by right clicking the right pane and click new, then DWORD value
4. Name the key as NoTrayItemsDisplay
5. Double click the key after creation and set the value as 1
6. Close registry and restart your computer in order for the settings to take into effect.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You can disable the host computer (remote user) from providing input. 
If you configure TeamViewer host giving yourself Full Access, then you can use the "Action" tool while connected to the remote user to disable their input.